# Safari Can't Get Uri Fragment After Google Oauth Callback

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I'm implementing Google OAuth 2.0 following this document: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

I set the following steps:

1. User click the Login Button and open up a new window.
2. Formatting the authenticating url and redirect that new window to Google.
3. User finished authentication login, Google redirect the access_token to my callback
4. The callback page validate the return access_token in URI fragment with # ( ex: `https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/oauthcallback#access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&nonce=DgkRrHXmyu3KLd0KDdfq`)

My problem is, for Chrome and Firefox, it works just fine. However, both Desktop Safari(9.0.1) and Mobile Safari(iOS 9.2) failed on receiving any hash params: [Safari Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFvR7.png)

Is that I'm implementing the wrong OAuth steps?

---

Part of my code:

- Step 1

  ```
  let that = this;
  let oauthWindow = window.open("", "oauthWindow", "height=518,width=964");

  that.setState(Object.assign({}, that.state, {loaded: false}));

  Parse.Cloud.run("google_util_request_login").then(function(result) {

      console.log(decodeURIComponent(result));

      oauthWindow.location = decodeURIComponent(result);

  }, function (error) {
      that.setState(Object.assign({}, that.state, {errorMessage: error, loaded: false}));
  });
  ```
- Step 2: *google_util_request_login* is a cloud function which will return the formatting url.

  - Github Repo: **github.com/bblurock/parse-cloud-with-google-twitter-oauth/blob/master/index.js#L22-L40**
    (sorry for the inconvenience, my reputation is not enough to post more than two links)

Comment: I'm also having this issue, did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I am also getting same problem, Have you find any solution? Then please share so i will be able to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Safari (unlike Firefox and Chrome) may strip the `#...` from a URI when a server redirects to another URI.

In my situation I had was using the redirect_uri `http://localhost:8080/auth-callback.html/` which my local server was redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/files/auth-callback.html/`.

In your example you mention the redirect_uri 
`https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/oauthcallback`. When I go to that uri I don't get redirected anywhere else so this may not be useful in your specific situation but if there is a more explicit path for that page then perhaps try that.

Sorry if this doesn't solve your problem but I am sure it will help someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, creating an app using Asana's API and Oauth...worked fine on Chrome, FF, and even IE 11 but not Safari.

This is what finally worked for me:
https://community.auth0.com/t/hash-gets-lost-on-safari-webkit-browsers/7263/8

Safari needed a '/' after at the end of the redirect URI:
"https://www.somedomain.com/somepathname/"

That, and don't include the actual file at the end of the redirect URI, i.e. "index.php".